# What is the right algorithm for orienting the yellow corners. Beginners method 3x3

Tags: rubiks-cube

> What is the right algorithm for orienting the yellow corners? Beginners method 3x3
>
> I have tried about 2-3 websites but they don't have the algorithms. Could I have some help with the algorithms? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to get a yellow cross on the top then you have to get a yellow corner 
Here:

[image] 
 Here:

[image]

or Here:

[image]

Once you have done that you need to complete the following:

**R  U  Ri  U  R  U  U  Ri** 

OR
[image]

Then you should have a completely yellow top.